# Cannot install mongo node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, backend

**MONGO HELP** 
I have tried many times to install mongo but I failed. I also checked my network cable but it is working. I am really worried for this kinda problem. please see my command output and help me.

```
$ npm i mongobd

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongobd - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'mongobd@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tariq/.npm/_logs/2022-05-07T09_03_57_665Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled it.

You want `npm i mongodb` not mongobd.

--

In the future, you can go to https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mongo and search for the package you want to find the exact command/name.